# Creating a dynamic monthly tab where we can click on a month and details will appear below using Oracle-Apex

Tags: oracle-apex

I am new to Oracle Apex. I'm currently trying to create an Application on attendance, leaves and payroll management system. What I want to do is to create a payroll processing page where there will be month tabs(more like buttons showing month and year) where with one click we can navigate through different months and view details of that month(allowances, deductions, leaves, salary etc.) but I can't seem to find any way to do this. Thanks.[The image shows how I want it to look.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNnXe.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list and use the "Tabs" list template. Create a dynamic list and make each target point to that same page with a different argument.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! But can it be updated dynamically too? like always showing current month in the middle tab and previous months and next months on left side and right side respectively?

Comment: A dynamic list means it is based on a sql query so yes

Comment: I'm trying it but it I don't think I completely understood what you said, can you elaborate it. Thanks for helping me out sir.

Comment: What exactly is not clear ? Pls provide as much info as possible

Comment: Where do I make that LOV? And what dynamic sql statement do I need to write to display both month and year in each tabs, sir?

Comment: It is not a "LOV", it is a "List". You can create it under "Shared Components > Navigation > Lists".

Comment: to write dynamic sql for a rolling nr of dates - check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62201907/sql-showing-rolling-4-months-looking-for-fiscal-year/

Comment: I've done it in another way, though I don't think it's the appropriate solution, I've uploaded it on youtube, would you kindly give your opinion if it's a good way to do it? The video link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KSfFCqt42Ao&t=319s&ab_channel=AdnansShenanigans

Comment: It depends on your requirements. You specifically asked about tabs in your question. Doing it with a popup lov works like you have done works just fine too although I would take a select list instead of a popup lov - that is less clicks for the end user

Comment: Pls don't ask followup questions in comments - that is a mess to answer and of no use to anyone else who could learn from this post

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I've deleted it